# Qt signals and slots between dialog and MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

Many tutorials about signals and slots in Qt have a bi-directional exchange of data between two dialogs.

In my example below, I am not trying to exchange any data, I am trying to call the updateComboBox method of the mainWindow class on the close (accept) of a dialog window.

**How do I call the MainWindow::updateComboBox function?**

Do I need slot connect code in the function that opens the dialog?

I'm working with Qt 5.1.

My attempt at the signals and slots:

**addGroup.h**

```
signals:
        void updateCombo();
```

**addGroup.cpp**

```
void addGroup::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    ...
    qry...
    if (qry.exec())
    {
        //connect(addGroup, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(updateCombo()));
        //connect(this, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(updateCombo()));
        emit updateCombo();
    }

}
```

**MainWindow.h**

```
public slots:
    void updateComboBox();
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::updateComboBox()
{
    ...
    qry...
}
```

Solution:

```
QObject:connect(addGroup,SIGNAL(updateCb()), this, SLOT(updateComboBox()));
```

As answered. I forgot 1 trailing parenthesis also.

Comment: Look up **where/when** and **how** to connect signals to slots. Because it isn't **after** emitting the signal and it isn't without a pointer to `MainWindow` instance.

Comment: Kids these days. Thanks for the direction at least Logic. Jak se mas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your updateComboBox method in the slots area and type(in the fuction you create and show the dialog window)the following order:

```
addGroup ag;
QObject::connect(&ag,SIGNAL(updateCombo()),this,SLOT(updateComboBox()));
```